# Always use a python virtual environment everywhere

Tags: 18.04, python3, virtualenv

I am new to Ubuntu and Python virtualenv. Since I realized the importance of virtualenv, I'd like to use it by default whenever I run python(from installing packages) so that I don't need to run `source bin/activate` every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment, it should be **activated** **(*manually or automatically*)** through running:

```
source PATH_TO_MY_ENV/bin/activate
```

However, when you **don't want to type this every time** and want to run it **automatically** by your **desktop start-up**, you should follow these **three** steps:

**1.** Create a shell script `activate_my_env.sh` and put the above
    mentioned command in it:

```
# activate_my_env.sh

source PATH_TO_MY_ENV/bin/activate
```

**2.** Then, you need to change the **permissions** for `activate_my_env.sh` script to be
**executable** 
(`chmod +x`):

```
chmod +x /path_to_your_file/activate_my_env.sh
```

**NOTE:** In this step you can also activate your environment **without typing** `source my_env/bin/activate`, but still need to run your script with this command:

```
./activate_my_env
```

**3.** Finally, in order to run the shell script **automatically**, you should set it to be **run by start-up / reboot** of your system:

- **A.** edit *contab* file:

  > crontab -e
- **B.** add the following line to this contab file:

  > @reboot  /path_to_you_file/**activate_my_env.sh**

Reboot your system and you should have your **virtual environment activated automatically**, after every **ubuntu startup**.

More about [Running Shell Script by Ubuntu Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

Comment: venv is per-shell instance. Neither ./active_my_env nor the cron will work

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to install `Anaconda` or `Miniconda`. It creates a virtual environment named `base` and makes it the default. So whenever you fire up your terminal, you will have `base` activated. Everything you install using conda or pip will be installed in the `base`.
Now please note that you may still need to use virtual environments. For example, you may have a Django 2.0 project and a Django 1.0 project. Then you need to keep 2 different virtual environments (say `venv1` and `venv2`) with Django 2.0 in the `venv2` and Django 1.0 in `venv1`. Otherwise you will have dependency errors.